# Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive.

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am getting error

**Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the \\ section in the application configuration.**

In my web.config and page i set enableSessionState="true"

```
public class PageBase : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public PageBase()
    {
        if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["ProgramID"].ToString())) && 
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["UserID"].ToString())) && 
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["CompanyID"].ToString())) && 
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["LanguageID"].ToString())))
        {
            Response.Redirect("SessionExpire.aspx", false);
        }
    }
}
```

i have written this one inside a class which is inherited from Web.Ui.Page.

Can you please help me out to solve this issue.

what i am missing .

please help

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Session` is not available (yet) during the **construction** of  your `Page`, try this instead:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["ProgramID"].ToString())) && 
        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["UserID"].ToString())) && 
        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["CompanyID"].ToString())) && 
        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["LanguageID"].ToString())))
    {
        Response.Redirect("SessionExpire.aspx", false);
    }

    base.OnInit(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem went away simply by using `HttpContext.Current.Response` instead